# Я написал код через Python в Sublime для мониторинга курса $, но выдает оишбку Currency = Currency() NameError: name 'Currency' is not defined

Tags: python, sublime-text

```
import  requests    #   Модуль  для обработки   URL
from    bs4 import  BeautifulSoup   #   Модуль  для работы  с   HTML
import  time    #   Модуль  для остановки   программы

#   Основной    класс
class   currency:
    #   Ссылка  на  нужную  страницу
    DOLLAR_RUB  =   'https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%81+%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0&rlz=1C1GGRV_enRU923RU923&ei=L0iNYMuIOaGvrgSfqKuYDw&oq=%D0%BA%D1%83&gs_lcp=Cgdnd3Mtd2l6EAEYATIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIKCAAQsQMQgwEQQzIECAAQQzIHCAAQsQMQQzIICAAQsQMQgwEyBQgAELEDMgQIABBDMgQIABBDMggIABCxAxCDATIICC4QsQMQgwE6AggAUJaVD1jOlQ9g9qAPaAJwAngAgAFuiAHCApIBAzAuM5gBAKABAaoBB2d3cy13aXqwAQDAAQE&sclient=gws-wiz'
    #   Заголовок   для передачи    вместе  с   URL
    headers =   {'Mozilla/5.0   (Windows    NT  10.0;   Win64;  x64)    AppleWebKit/537.36  (KHTML, like    Gecko)  Chrome/90.0.4430.93 Safari/537.36'}

    current_converted_price =   0
    difference  =   5   #   Разница после   которой будет   отправлено  сообщение   на  почту
    def _init_(self):
        # Установка курса валюты при создании обьекта
        self.current_converted_price = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))

        # Метод для получения курса валюты
        def get_currency_price(self):
            # Парсим всю страницу
            full_page = requests.get(self.DOLLAR_RUB, headers=self.headers)

            # Разбираем через BeautifulSoup
            soup = BeautifulSoup(full_page.content, 'html.parser')

            # Получаем нужное для нас значение и возвращаем его
            convert = soup.findALL("span", {"class": "DFlfde SwHCTb", "data-precision": 2})
            return convert[0].text

        # Проверка изменения валюты
        def check_currency(self):
            currency = float(self.get_currency_price().replace(",", "."))
            if currency >= self.current_converted_price + self.difference:
                print("Курс сильно вырос, нелезь, она тебя сожрет")
            elif currency <= self.current_converted_price - self.difference:
                print("Курс сильно  упал,   делай   грязь   бро")

            print("Сейчас курс: 1 доллар = " + str(currency))
            time.sleep(3) # Засыпание программы на 3 секунды
            self.check_currency()


#   Создание    обьекта и   вызов   метода
Currency = Currency()
currency.check_currency()
```

Comment: Ну, простейшая же ошибка. У вас имя класса с маленькой буквы, а создаете объект класса с большой буквы. `Currency = currency()`. А, затем обращаетсь к объекту снова с мальенкой, хотя у вас он задан с большой. Названия классов делайте с большой буквы, обращайтесь к классу как он задан. Переменные с маленькой

Comment: currency.check_currency()
AttributeError: type object 'currency' has no attribute 'check_currency' вот что начало выдавать